# I want to write an ROT 13 Encoder in python

Tags: python, encoding

I wanted to write a ROT 13 Encoder in python. I have never used python before. The encoder i want should I tried writing a script but its only able to do the basic ROT 13. Here is one of the script i have been using

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num_chars = len(alphabet)
rot_amt = 13

string_input = input('Enter a string: ')
string_output = ''

for curr_char in string_input:
    char_loc = alphabet.index(curr_char)
    new_loc = (char_loc + rot_amt) % num_chars
    string_output += alphabet[new_loc]

print(string_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have heard of Zen of Python, which is printed when you `import this`.
It actually uses the rot13 encoding. You may see its source in official cPython git [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/this.py)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you only forgot to change to upper case:

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num_chars = len(alphabet)
rot_amt = 13

string_input = input('Enter a string: ')
string_output = ''

for curr_char in string_input:
    char_loc = alphabet.index(curr_char.upper())
    new_loc = (char_loc + rot_amt) % num_chars
    string_output += alphabet[new_loc]

print(string_output)
```

Comment: This Actually worked. I just have one last question. How can i convert the input to ASCII

Answer (score 0):

Convert the input to uppercase and your script will work fine.
You could do it while taking input with the `upper()` function:

```
string_input = input('Enter a string: ').upper()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simple script:

```
import codecs
s  = input("Input your text: ")
os = codecs.encode( s, "rot13" )
print(os)
```